# CpxObjective for general expressions (NotSupportedException was unhandled) CPLEX .NET API

Tags: c#, c++, .net, cplex

I am trying to convert codes which was written in C++ with CPLEX API to .NET API. On the line cplex.AddMinimize(obj), I got NotSupportedException "CpxObjective for general expressions". I've searched but nothing found about it.. Could you please help me?

Here is the exception details:
    System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
      Message=CpxObjective for general expressions
      Source=ILOG.CPLEX
      StackTrace:
           konum: ILOG.CPLEX.CpxObjective.SetExpr(INumExpr expr)
           konum: ILOG.CPLEX.CpxObjective..ctor(ObjectiveSense sense, CpxNumExpr expr, String name)
           konum: ILOG.CPLEX.CplexModeler.Objective(ObjectiveSense sense, INumExpr expr, String name)
           konum: ILOG.CPLEX.CplexModeler.AddObjective(ObjectiveSense sense, INumExpr expr, String name)
           konum: ILOG.CPLEX.CplexModeler.AddMinimize(INumExpr expr)
           konum: WROM.WROM.Main(String[] args) c:\Users\Tolgahan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WROM\WROM\WROM.cs içinde: satır 173
           konum: System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
           konum: System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
           konum: Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
           konum: System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
           konum: System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
           konum: System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
      InnerException:

```
.
.
.
List<INumExpr> exprList = new List<INumExpr>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimeUnit; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSlot; j++)
   {
      for (int k = 0; k < numberOfProduct; k++)
      {
         for (int m = 0; m < numberOfProductUnitType; m++)
         {
            exprList.Add(cplex.Prod(cplex.Prod(overstowageTime1D[j], slotCapacity2D[j][m]), W4D[i][j][k][m]));
         }
      }
   }
}
INumExpr obj = cplex.Sum(exprList.ToArray());
exprList.Clear();
exprList.Add(obj);


for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimeUnit; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < numberOfTimeUnit; j++)
   {
      for (int k = 0; k < numberOfSlot; k++)
      {
         for (int m = 0; m < numberOfProduct; m++)
         {
            for (int n = 0; n < numberOfProductUnitType; n++)
            {
               exprList.Add(cplex.Prod(travelTime1D[k], Y5D[i][j][k][m][n]));
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
obj = cplex.Sum(exprList.ToArray());

cplex.AddMinimize(obj);
exprList.Clear();
.
.
.
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are doing, you are defining the objective function as a sum of different variables multiplied by parameters. In the end you want to minimize the objective.Can you tell me what the line 
obj = cplex.Sum(exprList.ToArray());
does?

Comment: I solved the problem today. The problem was the type of travelTime and overstowagetime arrays. They were of the type of INumVar. I set their initial value with using NumVar method of Cplex class in for loop. (e.g. travelTime1D[i] = cplex.NumVar(0.0, 1.0, NumVarType.Float);) I changed the type of these arrays to double instead INumVar, and used direct initialization (e.g. travelTime1D[i] = 0.567) in for loop. And problem is solved. Thank you for your interest Mr.Urbaniak.